# I do not understand how does the calc() function works, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: css, transform, calc

Why can't I use this?

```
--inner-card-height: 156px;
transform: translate(0, calc(-1 * (var(--inner-card-height) / 4)));
```

but I can do this?

```
transform: translate(0, calc(var(--inner-card-height) * -1)));
```

will appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: You cannot divide a value like `156px` since it's not a number. Instead, try `calc(-1 / 4 * var(--inner-card-height))`

Comment: The first line does not seem to have error in syntax but this one `transform: translate(0, calc(var(--inner-card-height) * -1)));` may be having 1 more `)` than it should.